# Div not showing but numbers in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-dom

Following is the UI, in which each box I am trying to display after 1 sec delay - (Box1, 1 sec delay, Box2, 1 sec delay, Box3 ..so on)

[image]

Instead I am getting -

[image: Wrong image]

My React code and let me know what I am doing wrong here **&** why its showing numbers -

```
const CreateBox = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
    {/*<div className="box">{props.num}</div>*/}
    <div className="box"></div>
    </>
  )
} 

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h3>App</h3>
      {
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map((item) => {
          return setTimeout(() => {
            // return (<CreateBox num={item} />)
            return (<CreateBox />)
          }, 1000)
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const root = document.querySelector('#root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBLPMY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new timeout for every element in the array on every render, you could create an interval in `componentDidMount` and increment a number in your state until it reaches 10 and use this number in your render method instead.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(
        ({ count }) => ({ count: count + 1 }),
        () => {
          if (this.state.count === 10) {
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
        }
      );
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <h3>App</h3>
        {Array.from({ length: this.state.count }, (_, index) => (
          <CreateBox key={index} num={index + 1} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const CreateBox = props => {
  return <div className="box">{props.num}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setTimeout while looping. Instead set the timer inside the CreateBox component using state. If you remove the timeout you can see the boxes. To handle the delay pass the index * 1000 as a timer for each element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class CreateBox extends React.Component {
  state = {
    opacity: 0
  }

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=> this.setState({opacity: 1}),`${this.props.time}000`)  
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div style={this.state} className="box">{this.props.num}</div>
    )
  }
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h3>App</h3>
      {
        [1,2,3,'w',5,6,7,8,9,10].map((item, index) => <CreateBox num={item} time={index}/>)
        
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const root = document.querySelector('#root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const CreateBox = (props) => {
  return (
   <div className="box">{props.num}</div>
  )
} 

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h3>App</h3>
      {
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map((item) => {              
             return (<CreateBox num={item} />)
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
const root = document.querySelector('#root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
```